# Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle

I am new to react-native development. I was trying a simple react-native project from Facebook git hub. I have followed all the steps but when I try to run the project by typing

```
  react-native run-android
```

it simply shows me following error:

```
   info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can  disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
   Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
   info Starting JS server...
   info Launching emulator...
   info Successfully launched emulator.
   info Installing the app...
   Warning: No leading - on line 1 of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\lib\jvm.cfg'

   error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
   Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
   Warning: No leading - on line 1 of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\lib\jvm.cfg'

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

Comment: You might want to finish your sentence and/or question...

Comment: Well, what does the file mentioned ("C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\lib\jvm.cfg") look like? Have you edited it?

Comment: is it not runnig?

Comment: @GauravRoy nope. it starts the emulator and stops

Comment: @rameshkhadka did you find a solution please? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @ZuzuJH I reinstall Java in my computer and it worked for me.

Comment: that's was my problem too. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had a problem with my Java. I uninstall JDK and JRE and reinstall the latest version and it worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try these once :

```
1.reopen android studio as admin. build the gradle. if no issue, proceed on
access the android folder of your app. i.e c:\folder\app\android
2.type in gradlew clean
3.run react-native run-android
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest version of Java Development Kit, you'll need to **change the Gradle version** of your project so it can recognize the JDK. You can do that by going to **{project root folder}\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties** and changing the **distributionUrl** value to upgrade the Gradle version. You can check out here the [lastest releases](https://gradle.org/releases/) of Gradle

Answer (score 0):

**The error message you encountered suggests that there was a problem configuring the project ':rn-fetch-blob' in React Native when running the './gradlew clean' command. Specifically, it mentions that it could not load compiled classes for the build file located at 'D:\D-drive\mobile\mkc-student-app\node_modules\rn-fetch-blob\android\build.gradle' from the cache.**

**To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:**

**1.** Make sure you have a stable internet connection.

**2.** Delete the Gradle cache by navigating to the following directory:

- For Windows: C:\Users<your_username>.gradle\caches
- For macOS: /Users/<your_username>/.gradle/caches
- For Linux: /home/<your_username>/.gradle/caches

**3.**  After deleting the cache, run the './gradlew clean' command again.